# To open a web page in firefox by clicking an anchor tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Once the user clicks an anchor tag I need to open a page in Firefox.

Example:

```html
<!-- Currently the anchor tag is displaying in any of following browsers: 
     Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari, and Chrome -->
<a href="sample.html">Sample link to open in Firefox</a>
```

Once the user clicks the link, I need to open file *sample.html* in Firefox. Impossible is nothing. But I don’t know how to do this.

Is there is an option to do this in JavaScript, jQuery, or PHP?

Comment: Is that enclosed in <script> tags? The reason I asked is because you have used Javascript comments by using //. You can't put HTML tags inside a script tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot, from a given web-page, specify in which software a link should be opened.

At best, if your anchor points to a specific kind of file *(like a .doc)*, the system will know that it must use some other software than the browser *(like MS Word -- or ask the user which software he wants to use)*. But, for an HTML page, the browser will be used.

And your website has no control over this.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean exclusively in Firefox, **it can't be done**.

The best you can do is hide it from other browsers by sniffing the [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP) if the browser is not Firefox. But a different browser can easily present itself as Firefox (by spoofing the user agent).

Either way, it is not a good idea.

Comment: If the case to open in other browser, how to do this

Comment: @Mohan Ram: We can't force a web page to be opened in Firefox or any other web browser. When a user clicks a link, the target page will always open in the user's default browser which can be Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer or some other.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this anchor being displayed?  In general, the link will be opened with the same program that is displaying the anchor.  If not, it will launch whatever program is registered in the user's system to handle HTML files.  You cannot *force* the user's system to use any specific browser (what happens if that browser isn't installed)?